# How to create a form in SharePoint that modifies query string

Tags: forms, sharepoint, get

My request is simple.

I want to put a form (a text field let's say) on a Sharepoint page, with a submit button.

When i submit, I want the URL to be reposted with the `s="textfromtextfield"`.

Say i was on a url `http://site/site.aspx?p=x` clicking submit will take me to:

```
http://site/site.aspx?p=x&s="textfromtextfield"
```

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you want to open the page in SharePoint Designer and add/play with form actions. Check this page for details (rather than attempt to communicate it step by step):

<s>http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101191121033.aspx</s>

FYI. SharePoint Designer is now free for download from Microsoft.

If you have never edited a form in SharePoint Designer, this may help:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101191141033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If this button "is completely yours" and not one of sharepoint controls you might try writing the following code on the button click handling method on the server side.

```
Page.Response.Redirect(newUrl, true);
```